# G-WAN v7.12.6 can't visit the static contents

Tags: g-wan

G-WAN out-of-box is running no problem with the dynamic contents but can't visit the static contents.
I ran G-WAN with kk user(not root, no sudo). All files and directories are of kk user/group.
I installed it in localhost. When I typed `127.0.0.1:8080` in the browser, it returned:
 `Server not found
 Firefox can't find the server at www.index.html.`
It is strange that the returned server name was `www.index.html`
When I typed `127.0.0.1:8080/index.html`, it returned `404 file not found`.

How can I workaround these, until a new release is out?
This time, there is no error message in the log file.
(I installed G-WAN in Ubuntu 15.10)

UPDATE: ------------------------
There are two strange info from the served_from.c, as below:

```
This page was processed...

Using get_env():

by the Server:    0.0.0.0:8080:8080(hostname: 127.0.0.1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^(Should it be only one '8080'?)
Virtual Host:     /home/kk/dev/gwan_v7.12.6/0.0.0.0:8080/#0.0.0.0
HTTP method:      GET
HTTP request:     /?served_from
HTTP query:       served_from
HTTP entity:      (null)
Content-Encoding: 0
Content-Length:   0
Content-Type:     0
for the Client:   127.0.0.1:43199
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0


Using HTTP Headers to get the same information:

by the Server:    27.0.0.1:8080 (hostname: 27.0.0.1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^(Should it be 127.0.0.1 ?
                  The leading '1' is missing.)
HTTP method:      GET
HTTP entity:      -
Content-Encoding: 0
Content-Length:   0
Content-Type:     0
for the Client:   127.0.0.1:43199
ozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Acpt-Language:    n-US,en;q=0.5
Acpt-Encoding:    3: |GZIP|DEFLATE
Cookies:          -
```

Is there anything wrong in v7.12.6?

UPDATE 2 ================================
with the following steps, G-WAN v7.12.6 can't show static contents:
1. all files and directories are of the same user/group (i.e. kk)
2. out-of-box, listen to 8080
3. run ./gwan
cannot visit static contents.

with following changes, G-WAN works normally:
1. change directory 0.0.0.0.8080 to 0.0.0.0:80
2. run sudo ./gwan -d:kk:kk
everything is normal.

sorry for my mis-typing in the UPDATE2. It should be 0.0.0.0:80 (emphasize the colon). Actually, I typed it right in the directory name. Repeat:  ./gwan should work according to G-WAN's document, since the user launching the program is owning all the files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you can query the server for scripts then G-WAN is running fine. The problem is obviously a file permission issue, hence the error `404 file not found` you got for the query `127.0.0.1:8080/index.html`.

This system configuration problem will affect any program, not specifically G-WAN. Consult our [dedicated FAQ](http://www.gwan.ch/faq#404) to find how to correct it.

For the `served_from.c` script, feel free to display the IP address in the "correct" order and to cut the string at the expected position to avoid the listener port repetition.

---

UPDATE:

Your latest update says **"changing directory 0.0.0.0.8080 to 0.0.0.0:80 works"**. This was the problem: "0.0.0.0.8080" has never been a valid syntax for G-WAN.

Comment: Even when I change the permission to '-rwxrwxrwx 1 kk kk 7244 Jan 26 20:17 index.html', this file still can't be visited. (gwan is started with 'sudo ./gwan -d:kk:kk').  'kk' has been added to www-data.

Comment: How about the returned server name when the url is '127.0.0.1:8080", why is 'www.index.html'? Should it be "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: Surely, it is my problem on setting file permissions, because v7.12.6 can replace my previous site of v7.12.2 now.(by taking away the problematic script)

Comment: Though it can run now, but still strange. To visit my site, must explicitly type url of 'mysite.com/index.html', can not simply type 'mysite.com'.   Browser message is:
This site can’t be reached
index.html’s server DNS address could not be found.
Why is "index.html's server", why not mysite.com's server?

Comment: with the description in UPDATE 2, it seems that it may not be a problem of file permissions.

Comment: Your latest update says **"changing directory 0.0.0.0.8080 to 0.0.0.0:80 works"**. This was the problem: "0.0.0.0.8080" has never been a valid syntax for G-WAN.

Comment: sorry for my mis-typing in the UPDATE. It should be 0.0.0.0:80 (emphasize the colon). Actually, I typed it right in the directory name. Repeat:  ./gwan should work according to G-WAN's document, since the user launching the program is owning all the files and directories.